# How to print value of x1 and x2 using for loop

Tags: tcl

How to print the value of x1 and x2 using for loop in tcl , i am getting error while executing this code

```
set x1 2
set x2 3

for {set i 1} {$i <= 2} {incr i} {
  puts "$x{$i}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set x1 2
set x2 3

for {set i 1} {$i <= 2} {incr i} {
  puts "x$i : [set x$i]"
}
```